# Adding zeros after the decimal on a form

Tags: php, html

I'm hoping to solve this in pure html. I suspect a solution may not exist, and I'm willing to learn a PHP solution. If that doesn't exist either, I'll learn whatever language I must.

Take the following form for example

```
<form>
    Price $<input type="number" name="price"><br>
</form>
```

It may not immediately be obvious to the user that this field accepts cents as well as dollars. (By, for example, typing 1.1 for $1.10.)

The same issue will come up when I ask a customer how many kilograms they wish to order, it won't immediately be obvious to them that they can order 100 grams by typing "0.1"

What I would like is for the field to start as ".00" with the curser appearing on the left when clicked, but as soon as the user types "." it will overwrite the existing ".". When the user types further numbers, the first two digits should overwrite the existing 0s, and further digits will be disabled.

This way, the user will be prompted to consider if they want to specify a certain number of cents (for a price) or grams (for a weight) without a condescending text field explaining what a decimal point is.

Does a html solution exist? If not, what other solutions exist? (I don't know ANY solutions.)

**Example**

There seems to be some confusion among my answers as to what I'm asking for, so I created a quick and dirty example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <form>
        <br><br><br>
        Price $<input style="text-align:right" type="number" name="price" value=".00">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

(I know, style attribute inside a tag, I'm going to hell to burn for eternity.)

Using this, and photoshop, I created a simulation of the functionality I wanted, comic book style. [image: See it in action!]

As shown, I already know how to get the initial state. I thought this might be possible with one quick piece of code, but if it can't, I have broken the question down into its core components below:

1. How do I move the cursor to a in front of the decimal point when the user clicks to the right of the decimal point?
2. How do I make the text overwrite the initial decimal point with a new decimal point, and have it continue to overwrite?
3. How do I disallow extra decimal points?
4. How do I disallow the user from writing more than a predetermined number of digits? (two, in the example shown above)
5. How do I automatically replace characters deleted (by backspace for example) with a 0?

Up-votes to anyone who can answer at least one of the questions above, or at least reveals a valuable insight towards answering one of the questions above.

Sorry, this question is getting more complex than I initially thought it was.

**Update**

I'm beginning to expect a PHP solution doesn't exist either. I'm still quite new to coding, so I could be completely wrong, but this is why:

PHP is a server side language, and this task requires live instantaneous functionality on the client's end without waiting for a server to validate their request to delete a decimal point.

This functionality is too specific and advanced for html and CSS. Therefore, it must be achieved through something else. I'll still leave this question up here, in case anyone wants to have a stab at the answer, but my knowledge of other languages (like JavaScript) isn't quite advanced enough to compile individual core component answers into one final functional answer... yet.

So I'm going to busy myself updating my website using the skills I have for the tasks that require doing. Even when I'm ready to learn a new language, this is too advanced a problem to tackle straight away. But, when I'm learning new functions, if I discover something that will solve this problem, I'll post the full code back here for the community to reference in future.

Comment: i used a js library called number to format my input as i needed. If you google for it you should be able to find it

Comment: Thanks. Yeah, I think that will be the correct answer, but it's a bit advanced for me just yet.

Comment: it's just a very  simple library with examples on how to use it. it doesn't require much coding. And you can simply open a new question if you get stuck on how to use. [This](https://plugins.jquery.com/df-number-format/) is the library I am talking about